# word document from vba + Listformat

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to generate a MS Word document from an Excel VBA script.  In this example, I generate 10 lines of text.  In specific situation (represented here by a random variable), I want to apply special list formatting.

In this case I get error:  Method ApplyListTemplateWithLevel of object 'ListFormat' failed
I have tried several ways of doing this, with little success

```
Sub ToWord()

' In Tools|References, add reference to "Microsoft Word 12 Object Library"

Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim x As Integer

Set wdApp = New Word.Application

wdApp.Visible = True
wdApp.Activate
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add

    With wdApp.Selection
        For x = 1 To 10
            .TypeText ("a simple text string  ")
            .TypeText ("a simple text string  ")
            .TypeText ("a simple text string  ")
            .TypeText ("a simple text string  ")
            .TypeParagraph

             If Rnd > 0.5 Then
              ' crashes here...
              wdDoc.Range(.Paragraphs(x).Range.Start, .Paragraphs(x).Range.End) _
              .ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
              ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _                                            
              False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
              wdWord10ListBehavior
            End If

        Next x

    End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: Stupid question, but is it because you're breaking the line before your access operator? Do you get the same error if the line is `wdDoc.Range(.Paragraphs(x).Range.Start, .Paragraphs(x).Range.End).ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel`?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

wdDoc.Range(.Paragraphs(x).Range.Start, .Paragraphs(x).Range.End)

to

wdDoc.Paragraphs(x).Range